# Redirection of wp-login.php results in non working of Logout process

Tags: logout

I want to create Custom Login, Registration, Password Reset & Logout Page. For that I have added following code in my function.php file.

```
function custom_login_page() {
 $new_login_page_url = home_url(); // new login page
 global $pagenow;
 if( $pagenow == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {
    wp_redirect($new_login_page_url);
    exit;
 }
}
 add_action('init','custom_login_page');
```

Everything is working perfectly except the logout process. By adding this code a user is not getting logged out.

In short the Logout Process is not working. Plz Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have to trigger `wp_logout()` yourself in that case:

```
if ( $pagenow == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {
    if ( (isset($_GET['action'])) && ($_GET['action'] == 'logout') ) {
        wp_logout();
    }
    wp_redirect($new_login_page_url);
    exit;
}
```

That said, it sounds like a real pain to reinvent `wp-login.php` and handle the different form actions etc... a plugin such as [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) might be more suitable for a more bug-free solution.